# iText7 - PdfReader constructor locks non-pdf files

Tags: itext7

Consider the following C# code:

```cs
try
{
    using (new PdfReader(filename))
    {
    }
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(filename);
}
```

If `filename` points to a non-pdf file, `PdfReader` constructor throws exception (as expected), but also does not release the `FileStream` that it internally creates, despite being called in a `using` block. As a result, attempt to delete the file in `finally` block throws exception `The process cannot access the file '<filename>' because it is being used by another process.`

In fact, if constructor throws an exception, it should not result in locking any resources. So the above code should be deleting non-pdf files even when `PdfReader` constructor is called without the `using` block.

Obvious workaround is to instantiate `PdfReader` like this:

```cs
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (new PdfReader(fileStream))
{
}
```

It does work, but current behaviour of the `PdfReader` constructor overloads using `filename` argument is not expected.

Comment: Can someone who supports iText please reply. I'd say that a constructor that fails but also leaves locked resources is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug on the part of iText, but it's known issue and it's already fixed in the newest develop version. iText 7.1.16 version will contain this fix, but if you need this right now you can use SNAPSHOT version from the artifactory https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/snapshot

Comment: Here's also a link that describes how snapshot artifacts fetching can be configured: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-itext-7-for-net#InstallingiText7for.NET-InstallingSNAPSHOTbuilds